# Problema con password_verify en el login

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer el login con password_hash y tengo el problema al hacer password_verify, os confirmo que el password es correcto, que me guarda bien en la base de datos, pero y despues de debugear varias veces, el problema esta cuando hace el password_verify, no hace true y salta, y por mas que miro no veo el error. La primer parte del login es del controlador, entra en PersonaDAO cuando llama a loginHash, y la segunda parte es el metodo loginHash. Ya os digo cuando entra en loginHash en password_verify da false y no entra, pero compruebo en depuracion, que el password es el correcto, que passwordE recupera bien de la base de datos la cadena.

```
// Botón de login
if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])) {
    // Comprobación reCaptcha v3
    // Construyendo el POST request
    $recaptchaURL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $recaptchaSecret = '6LchkOQZAAAAAG2wQ5HML903c3RT6pEXfwSO9zHz';
    $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['recaptchaResponse'];

    // Haciendo el requiest y decodoficándolo
    $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptchaURL . '?secret=' . $recaptchaSecret . '&response=' . $recaptchaResponse);
    $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

    // Verificación de que el usuario es humano
    if ($recaptcha->success == true && $recaptcha->score >= 0.6) {
        // Recupero los valores del login
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        // Guardo en la sesion el correo del usuario
        $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $email;

        // Compruebo login correcto
        if (PersonDAO::loginHash($email, $password)) {

            // Compruebo si el usuario esta inactivo
            $userDni = PersonDAO::getDni($email);
            if (PersonDAO::isActivePersonDni($userDni) == 0) {
                header('Location: ../View/usuario_inactivo.php');
            } else {
                // Guardo el dni en la sesion
                $_SESSION['userDni'] = $userDni;
                // Guardo el rol en la sesion
                $_SESSION['userRol'] = PersonDAO::getRol($userDni);
                header('Location: ../View/home.php');
            }
        } else {
            header('Location: ../View/login_incorrecto.php');
        }
    } else {
        // Captcha inválido
        $_SESSION['mensaje-captcha'] = 'Error al validar su identidad. ¿Es usted un robot?';

        // Envio a la página de inicio con mensaaje de error
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
}

// Método para realizar el login
    static function loginHash($email, $password) {
        // Abro la conexion
        GestionBDD::conectarBDD();

        // Variable para controlar el login correcto
        $correcto = false;

        // Preparo la sentencia SQL
        $query = 'SELECT email, password FROM ' . Constants::$PEOPLE . ' WHERE email = ?;';
        $stmt = GestionBDD::$conexion->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $val1);

        // Valores de la sentencia
        $val1 = $email;

        // Ejecuto y guardo el resultado
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email, $passwordE);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        // Si hay resultados y es correcta la comprobación devuelvo true
        if (!empty($row)) {
            if (password_verify($password, $row['passwordE'])) {
                $correcto = true;
            }
        }

        // Cierro la sentencia y la consulta
        $stmt->close();
        GestionBDD::cerrarBDD();

        // Devuelvo si es o no correcto el login
        return $correcto;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

En tu código hay varios problemas, vamos a verlos uno por uno:

1. En el `SELECT` tu columna se llama `password`, no se llama `passwordE`, por tanto, esto es incorrecto:

   ```
    if (password_verify($password, $row['passwordE'])) {
   ```

   Es un despiste que tiene **poca relevancia para este caso**, pero debes considerar este tipo de errores tontos que te pueden hacer perder varios días.
2. Aquí el problema grave es que el uso que haces de `fetch()` no es correcto. [Según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), `fetch()` no te devolvería un recurso con los datos como aparentemente intentas hacer aquí:

   ```
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
   ```

   El Manual es claro en este punto. Siempre que vayas a usar un método, revisa el apartado **Valores devueltos** y los ejemplos de código. Estas son las posibilidades de devolución de `fetch()`: `TRUE`, `FALSE` o `NULL`. Nunca un recurso en el cual poder encontrar datos haciendo algo como `$row['columna']`

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Entonces, si estás bindeando los datos a variables:

   ```
   $stmt->bind_result($email, $passwordE);
   ```

   Significa que los datos estarán en esas variables cuando hagas el `fetch()` y en la comparación tendrías que usar la variable, algo así: **`if (password_verify($password, $passwordE)) {`**. Pero hay un poco de spaghetti en tu código y podemos optimizar un poco, si te interesa...

La función podría re-escribirse del siguiente modo (al final explico lo que se ha optimizado y por qué):

```
  static function loginHash($email, $password) {
    // Variable para controlar el login correcto
    $correcto = false;

    // Abro la conexion
    GestionBDD::conectarBDD();

    // Preparo la sentencia SQL
    $query = 'SELECT password FROM ' . Constants::$PEOPLE . ' WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1;';
    $stmt = GestionBDD::$conexion->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    // Ejecuto y guardo el resultado
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($passwordE);

    // Si hay resultados y es correcta la comprobación devuelvo true
    if ( $stmt->fetch() && password_verify($password, $passwordE) ) {
            $correcto = true;
    }

    // Cierro la sentencia y la consulta
    $stmt->close();
    GestionBDD::cerrarBDD();

    // Devuelvo si es o no correcto el login
    return $correcto;
}
```

Cosas que he optimizado:

- `SELECT` solamente de `password` que es el dato que interesa obtenerse, ningún otro. Se agrega además `LIMIT 1` a la instrucción, porque es una verificación.
- Se hace `bind_param()` de `$email`, porque su única función aquí es ser criterio del `WHERE`, ese manejo innecesario de declarar `$val1` no tiene ningún sentido más que crear código spaghetti.
- Se hace `bind_result()` de `$passwordE` que es el dato que se ha indicado en el `SELECT` y único dato que se va a verificar.
- La creación de `$row` no tiene sentido, por lo ya explicado en el punto 2. Tampoco tendría sentido una verificación con  `empty()`. Aquí hemos hecho una doble verificación, de `fetch()` y de `password_verify()`, **conforme al tipo de valor que ambas funciones devuelven**. No hace falta liar tanto el código en este caso.

Así debería funcionar, si no hay otros problemas que escapan a este contexto. Doy por supuesto que:

*a*) Usaste `password_hash` al momento del `INSERT`;

*b*) Tu columna `password` tiene un tipo de dato/tamaño adecuado según el tipo de encriptado que has usado para el hash.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, como siempre por supuesto. Solo una pequeña duda que me surge, usas `Constants::$PEOPLE`, pero las constantes en php se suelen usar sin el símbolo `$`, no? Quiero decir, cuando defines algo como `const TABLA_USUARIOS= "usuarios";`, el $ no se usa, no? Disculpa mi pregunta, php no es mi fuerte.

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B, esa parte la dejé tal y como la tenía OP. Supongo que tiene una clase estatica `Constants` y dependiendo de su versión de PHP y lo que haya en esa clase, bien podría hacer algo como esto: `Constants::PEOPLE`. Ver [esta nota del Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php#108717) y las explicaciones al respecto.

Comment: @Benito-B rectifico mi comentario anterior. Puede que OP tenga una clase `Constants` con un miembro como este: `public static $PEOPLE`. De ese modo funciona tal y como esta ahora, pero quizá debería considerar un tipo de definición más conforme a la programación estandarizada en PHP. Por tanto, OP puede hacer así en la clase: `const PEOPLE="elValor";` y obtenerlo así: **`Constants::PEOPLE`**. Tu observación no es banal, pues esta línea podría estar fallando en su código `Constants::$PEOPLE` si esa propiedad no está definida de un modo conforme a ese tipo de llamada en su clase `Constants`