# ¿Cómo paso MYSQLI a PDO?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quisiera saber si pueden ustedes identificar cuál es el inconveniente que presento en este código. La línea del error es: `"header("location: index.php");"`. No sé si se debe a que está mal cerrada con los ";". Aún no he podido solucionar el problema.
Estoy usando `XAMPP` para la realización de las pruebas. Es un código simple para saber si logra conectar con la base de datos y después ir trabajándolo.
Gracias por la ayuda!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once "config/config.php";
     
    function verificar_login($dni,$password,&$result) {
        $sql = "SELECT dni, password FROM members WHERE dni = '$dni' and password = '$password'";
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = 0;
     
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
        {
            $count++;
            $result = $row;
        }
     
        if($count == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
     
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
     
    if(!isset($_SESSION['dniid']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            if(verificar_login($_POST['dni'],$_POST['password'],$result) == 1)
            {
                $_SESSION['dniid'] = $result->dniid
                header("location: index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div class="error">Su DNI es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>";
            }
        }
    ?>
     
    <form action="" method="post" class="login">
        <div><label>DNI</label><input name="dni" type="text" ></div>
        <div><label>Password</label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
        <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
    </form>
    <?php
    } else {
        echo 'Su usuario ingreso correctamente.';
        echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
    }
```

También adjunto el código de conexion.php que está programado en formato PDO. La idea es que en base al código de conexión en PDO se pudiera adaptar el código de login.php que está hecho en mysqli.

```
<?php
//Archivo config para Producción
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

//database credentials
##para conectarse a la BBDD del servidor de produccion##
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBPORT','3306');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','123');
define('DBNAME','siriodb');

//application address
##para uso en el servidor de desarrollo local##
define('DIR','https://www.test.com.ar/');
define('SITETITLE','Login');
define('SITEEMAIL','email@email.com.ar');
define('SITECUSTOMER','Pagina test'); // Ej Nombre de empresa

//Conexion con setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); utilizada para la mayoria de las consultas

try {
    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=".DBPORT.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);//Suggested to uncomment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    //echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    echo "Fallo al conectar a la BBDD Remota (db1)";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Te falta cerrar la línea anterior con punto y coma:`$_SESSION['dniid'] = $result->dniid;`

Comment: Sí, lo he hecho pero me tira otro error en el código, en este caso: **syntax error, unexpected identifier "error", expecting "," or ";"**
 En la linea `echo "<div class="error">Su DNI es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>";`

Comment: mysql_query esta obsoleto, deberías usar PDO o mysqli_

Comment: Sí, tenes mucha razón. Estoy trabajando con PHP 7 y debería comenzar a usar mysqli, lo corregiré. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Muestra lo que tienes en `config.php`, pues no se sabe cómo obtienes la conexión, si es mediante un método, si es directamente, etc. En los comentarios pusiste un bloque `try` para conectar, pero falta contexto.

Comment: Disculpa, ahí compartí el PDO de conexión. Agradezco tu paciencia, si falta algo más estoy atento a tu respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa la respuesta editada. He adaptado el archivo de conexión para que te retorne el objeto `$pdo`  y he migrado el código anterior (mysqli) a PDO. Me dices el resultado. Revisa también la nota al final sobre las contraseñas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, chequearé tu código recomendado y te comentaré cualquier duda :)

Comment: Parece estar funcionando todo a su normalidad. Ahora, el inconveniente es que una vez ingresado estos datos, cuando termina la consulta ejecuta el echo de "Su DNI es incorrecto" y el config.php lanza otro echo con el mensaje de que hay un error en la conexión. Posiblemente sea que aún no logra terminar de enviar la consulta?

Comment: Cuando visito en mi navegador config.php no envía ningún mensaje, queda la página en blanco. Eso supone que la conexión con la base de datos la realiza con éxito, pero a la hora de consultar datos no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos errores en tu código:

1. Te falta cerrar la línea anterior al `header location` con punto y coma: `$_SESSION['dniid'] = $result->dniid;`
2. En las cadenas con dobles comillas, debes escapar la comillas interiores con `\`, aquí no lo estás haciendo: `echo "<div class="error">Su DNI es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>";` Así el error desaparecería: `echo "<div class=\"error\">Su DNI es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>";` porque escapas las comillas que hay para `class="error"`.

Por otra parte, si estás usando PDO, el código debe ser adaptado a PDO. De igual modo, el archivo donde conectas a PDO tiene que tener alguna forma de acceder a la conexión. Yo he creado en dicho archivo una función `getConnection()` que te retorna sea el objeto `$db` (que es la conexión)  o `null` en caso de fallo.

El archivo sería así:

```
<?php
  //Archivo config para Producción
  function getConnection()
  {
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    //set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');

    //database credentials
    ##para conectarse a la BBDD del servidor de produccion##
    define('DBHOST','localhost');
    define('DBPORT','3306');
    define('DBUSER','root');
    define('DBPASS','123');
    define('DBNAME','siriodb');

    //application address
    ##para uso en el servidor de desarrollo local##
    define('DIR','https://www.test.com.ar/');
    define('SITETITLE','Login');
    define('SITEEMAIL','email@email.com.ar');
    define('SITECUSTOMER','Pagina test'); // Ej Nombre de empresa

    //Conexion con setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); utilizada para la mayoria de las consultas

    try {
        //create PDO connection
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=".DBPORT.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);//Suggested to uncomment on production websites
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
        return $db;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //show error
        //echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        echo "Fallo al conectar a la BBDD Remota (db1)";
        return NULL;
        exit;
    }
  }
```

Ahora adaptamos el código a PDO y de paso usamos **consultas preparadas** pues tu código no es seguro por el simple hecho de usar PDO. La seguridad consiste en **no pasar datos externos directamente en las consultas**.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once "config/config.php"; 
    function verificar_login($dni,$password,&$result) 
    {
        $pdo=getConnection();
        if ($pdo) 
        {
          $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE dni = :dni and password = :password";
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindParam(":dni", $dni, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->execute();
          $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
          return ($count > 0);
        } 
        else 
        {
          echo "Error en la conexión";
          return false;
        }
        
    }
     
    if(!isset($_SESSION['dniid']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            if(verificar_login($_POST['dni'],$_POST['password'],$result) > 0)
            {
                $_SESSION['dniid'] = $result->dniid;
                header("location: index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div class=\"error\">Su DNI es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>     
    <form action="" method="post" class="login">
        <div><label>DNI</label><input name="dni" type="text" ></div>
        <div><label>Password</label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
        <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
    </form>
```

### Edit

He simplificado el código en los siguientes aspectos:

1. Para verificar si hay registros es mejor hacer una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` la cual traerá la cantidad de filas que existan con ese criterio.
2. Dado que este tipo de consultas arroja una sola fila, no hace falta recorrer las filas e ir incrementando un contador como hacías en tu código original. Simplemente puedes obtener los resultados de la columna con `fetchColumn()`.
3. Luego puedes retornar `true` o `false` con algo así: `return ($count > 0)`. Esto retornará `true` si la cantidad de filas es mayor que cero o `false` en caso contrario.
4. En la llamada a la función hemos cambiado esto: `if(verificar_login($_POST['dni'],$_POST['password'],$result) == 1)` por esto: `if(verificar_login($_POST['dni'],$_POST['password'],$result))`, porque hemos hecho que `verificar_login()` devuelva un booleano `true` o `false` sin más. Si la idea es comprobar que existen registros, no debes comparar contra `1`, porque el código no funcionará si por algún motivo hay más de una fila y eso podría ocurrir en algunos contextos.
5. Finalmente, los `echo` que hay después del `form` no tienen ningún sentido. En caso de ingresar correctamente tú estás haciendo un `location` más arriba, eso redireccionará a otra página, por lo que no estarás ya en el contexto actual para mostrar ese contenido. Si quieres mostrar mensajes o lo que sea tendrás que pasarlos a la página a la que redireccionas o replantear la forma de organizar el código en cuanto a las redirecciones.

### Nota sobre la verificación de claves.

En los comentarios salió el tema de `password_hash()` y `password_verify()`, pero no has aclarado nada al respecto. Si al guardar el password creaste un hash y lo guardaste en la BD, ahora debes usar `password_verify()` para comprobar. Si no sabes cómo funciona consulta la documentación o revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/408826/29967).

Comment: Increíble, esto funcionó al 100%. Agradezco enormemente tu ayuda :).

Comment: @Francisco, me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Considera también simplificar tu código, hay muchas cosas repetitivas e innecesarias en el mismo.

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo. Honestamente estoy teniendo conflictos en el login. Cuando pongo el DNI y contraseña me salta DNI incorrecto cuando todas sus credenciales están bien colocadas.

Comment: Debe ser por lo que me tratas de decir, que hay cosas innecesarias y repetitivas.

Comment: @Francisco revisa la respuesta con una propuesta de código mejorada. Al final he agregado una sección **Edit** con algunas cosas.

Comment: Este código está super mejor a lo que yo había optimizado. El único problema es que al finalizar la solicitud me envía a la página de "error, no se pudo procesar la solicitud".
 Lo que observé fue que la linea `$rec = mysql_query($sql);` no tenía la letra "i" al final de la l, ya que las nuevas versiones de php eliminaron "mysql_query". Ahora, cuando terminé de reemplazarlo por mysqli automáticamente pongo las credenciales correctas pero aún así me envía el "echo" que dice "DNI incorrecto" cuando en realidad está todo bien. No logro identificar el por qué.

Comment: Otro dato es que las claves están totalmente encriptadas, cifradas. Puede ser faltante lineas que declaren "password_hash"?

Comment: Insertando "error_reporting" en el código tuve la posibilidad de ver los errores de por qué no consulta con la base de datos. Me aparecen los 3 siguientes errores

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/c2210135/public_html/login/login2.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/c2210135/public_html/login/login2.php on line 11

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/c2210135/public_html/login/login2.php on line 12

Comment: No me había dado cuenta del pequeño gran error de la i faltante. Por otra parte, si guardaste la contraseña usando `password_hash`, debes usar `password_verifiy` para comprobar el hash. Es importante que menciones ese tipo de cosas en la pregunta.

Comment: También, tienes que pasar la conexión a `mysqli_query` junto con la instrucción SQL que quieres ejecutar. ¿Cómo se llama tu variable de conexión?

Comment: Yo he enlazado todo lo que respecta a la conexión con la base de datos en un archivo llamado config.php.
 Según el sitio, este archivo hace la conexión a la base de datos con éxito. Los tengo declarados por define('DBHOST','LOCALHOST'); y así sucesivamente los datos que siguen para conectar con la base de datos.
 Después inicia un PDO que lo dejaré en el próximo comentario

Comment: `try {
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=".DBPORT.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
 //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
 //show error
    //echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    echo "Fallo al conectar a la BBDD Remota (db1)";
    exit;
}`

Comment: Y para que pueda traer este archivo a mi login.php, lo declaré debajo de "session_start" del siguiente modo: `include_once "config/config.php";`

Comment: Pues si estás usando PDO debes cambiar todo el código. En la pregunta el código que mostraste es de `mysqli`  que es una de las clases de conexión posibles para manejar la base de datos MySQL desde PHP, mientras que PDO es otra clase que permite lo mismo. Pero **`mysqli`  y `PDO` son dos clases distintas**, por lo que sus métodos también son distintos. Confírmame si es PDO y adaptaré el código. Pero es importante que tengas claro que PDO es una cosa y mysqli es otra, cuando planteas preguntas aquí el contexto y las herramientas que usas deben estar depurados.

Comment: Utilizo PDO. Estuve viendo que tenes razón, aunque el PDO tiende a ser un tipo de código más seguro y difícil de inyectar teniendo en cuenta que mysqli tiende a intentar eso.
 El archivo PDO lo extraje de un config instalado en otro sistema, viene por eso mi confusión entre pdo y msysqli.
 Si puedes readaptarlo me ayuda mucho a entender mejor cuestiones del código. Muchas gracias por tu soporte, estoy agradecido con vos.

Comment: Esto tampoco es cierto: *aunque el PDO tiende a ser un tipo de código más seguro y difícil de inyectar teniendo en cuenta que mysqli tiende a intentar eso*. Tanto PDO como mysqli **son seguros, a condición de que escribas código seguro**, por código seguro entiéndase, escribir consultas preparadas para pasar datos que vienen del exterior. De hecho, en tu caso actual, el código es inseguro, uses PDO o mysqli, porque precisamente no estás usando consultas preparadas. Actualizaré el código, pero primero debes editar la pregunta para ver cómo obtienes la conexión a PDO, pues eso no queda claro.

Comment: Perfecto, me quedó más claro ahora. No tenía en cuenta ese dato. Ahí edité la pregunta, creería que está bien