# password_hash desencriptar

Tags: php, encriptación

hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar  como puedo desencriptar un password_hash para el login al entrar lo encrypto asi

```
$password = password_hash($this->input->post('password',true),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

pero no se como sacarlo de mi base de datos y deceptriptarlo para compararlo en mi login

```
    public function log_in_correctly() {  
          $this->db->where('correo', $this->input->post('correo'));  
          $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password')); 
          
         
  $query = $this->db->get('usuarios');  
    if ($query->num_rows() ==1)  
    {  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }
```

Comment: Lo que guardas en BD no puede ni debe volver a si versión original. Tú sólo recibes la contraseña del usuario que inicia sesión, la encriptas y comparas los dos hashes. Profundiza sobre el funcionamiento de esa función password_hash y sobre qué es un hash

Comment: Las constraseña hasheadas se verifican con [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php). Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/256648/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: Si logras desencriptar el HASH me avisas para hacernos famosos :) #JK. Tienes que cifrar el password que escribe el usuario con el mismo algoritmo con el que está guardado en la BD y ahora si comparar HASH vs HASH.

Comment: @Alfabravo no funciona ya que cada que generas un hash te crea una serie diferente

Comment: Falso. Una buena función hash con ese propósito no te va a funcionar así ;)

Comment: @A.Cedano no entendi muy bien en que parte se pondria

Comment: @Alfabravo que podria usar para cifrar la contraseña

Comment: En [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/256746/29967) (punto 2), creo que lo expliqué claro. Al momento del INSERT se supone que usaste `password_hash`, entonces, cuando haces el `SELECT` tienes que usar `password_verify`. En la respuesta hay también un ejemplo de código. Ten en cuenta las otras cosas dichas allí, como la codificación. Y considera que, si no hiciste un hash, no podrás verificar. Una sin la otra no funcionará. El tema ha sido tratado aquí varias veces, revisa por ejemplo [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/408826/29967).

Comment: La respuesta que cita ACedano reemplaza tu función login. Le entregas el usuario y la contraseña que acabas de recibir. Las suposiciones sobre el hash que haces son incorrectas y, si estás encontrando algo diferente, debes detallarlo en la pregunta o no recibirás una respuesta útil

Comment: ok gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

para comparar las contraseñas usas password_verify, no de conviertes en norma.

EJ:

```
<?php

 $hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

 if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
 echo 'La contraseña es válida!';
 } else {
  echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
 }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar la clave tienes que compararlo de la siguiente manera.

```
password_verify($clave,$data_usuario->pa_clave);
```

compara la clave recibida `$clave`, contra la encriptada `$data_usuario->pa_clave` si es verdadero esta bien.